# How a php code is fired after html form submission?

Tags: php, html

this code is a simple form that write a text based on what a user types.

```
            <form  method="post">
                Colore: <input type="text" name="colore"></br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="inserisci colore">
              </form>


<?php

              $colore_inserito = $_POST['colore'];

                  switch ($colore_inserito) {

                  case "rosso":
                      echo "hai scelto il colore $colore_inserito";
                 break;

                  case "verde":
                              echo "hai scelto il colore $colore_inserito";
                  break;

                  case "giallo":
                              echo "hai scelto il colore $colore_inserito";
                  break;

                  default:
                            echo "non hai selezionato nessun colore rosso o verde o giallo";

}
            ?>
```

The php code is linked with the form just with the $_POST variable. What i don't understand is, in which way the php code get fired after a user presses the form button ?

In fact, $_POST is just a variable, i don't understand how php code get activated and the page refreshed to show the php output.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking a submit button submits the form it belongs to.

Submitting the form causes the browser to make an HTTP request.

The HTTP server receives the request and processes it.

The HTTP server recognises that the path is to be handled by a PHP file and executes it.